# writing tcp server -- buffering a stream

Tags: c++, c, string, tcp, buffer

```
#include <sys/socket.h> // for socket(), bind(), listen(), accept()
#include <netinet/in.h> // for PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP
#include <stdio.h>  // for printf(), perror()
#include <unistd.h> // for read(), write(), close()
#include <string.h> // for bzero()

#define DEMO_PORT 9723


int main( void )
{
    //-----------------------------------------
    // create an unnamed socket for the server
    //-----------------------------------------
    int sock = socket( PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );
    if ( sock < 0 )
    {
        perror( "opening stream socket" );
        return  -1;
    }
    printf( "\nsock=%d \n", sock );

    //----------------------------------------
    // construct a name for the server socket
    //----------------------------------------
    struct sockaddr_in  self;
    socklen_t       nlen = sizeof self;
    bzero( &self, sizeof self );
    self.sin_family = AF_INET;
    self.sin_port = htons( DEMO_PORT );
    self.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl( INADDR_ANY );
    if ( bind( sock, (sockaddr *)&self, nlen ) < 0 )
    {
        perror( "bind failed" );
        return  -1;
    }
    printf( "bind succeeded port: %d\n",DEMO_PORT);

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    // now create a connection queue and wait for some clients
    //---------------------------------------------------------
    if ( listen( sock, 5 ) < 0 )
    {
        perror( "listen failed" );
        return  -1;
    }
    printf( "listen succeeded \n" );


    //---------------------------------------------------
    // main loop to process clients' connection-requests
    //---------------------------------------------------
    while ( 1 )
    {
        sockaddr_in peer;
        socklen_t   plen = sizeof peer;
        bzero( &peer, plen );

        printf( "server waiting \n" );

        int client = accept( sock, (sockaddr *)&peer, &plen );
        if ( client < 0 ) { perror( "accept" ); break; }

        //---------------------------------------------
        // we can now read from or write to the client
        //---------------------------------------------
        char    ch;
        int index = 0;
        char get[1024];

        if ( read( client, &ch, 1 ) < 0 )
        {
            perror( "read" );
        }  


        bool go = true;


        while(go){

            if(ch != '/' && ch != '\r'){

                printf("read: %hhd\n", ch);

                get[index] = ch;
                printf( "got stuff: %s\n", get );

                index++;

                read(index, &ch, 1);


            } else {

                go = false;
                index = 0;
                close( client );
                printf( "server responded, connection closed" );


            }
        }


        //if ( write( client, &ch, 1 ) < 0 ) { perror( "write" ); break; }



    }

    close( sock );
    printf( "\n" );
}
```

the while(go) look never works and it buffers incorrectly. I do not see the pattern within the buffer or how it works.

What is the correct way to do this? to except a certain amount of bytes, store them in a string, then terminate the read if it reaches a newline character?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing index into the second read call where you should be passing client.

This may not be your only problem but I think it is one of them.

Comment: isnt client also an integer?

Comment: Yes although 'index' is probably not the right integer to be passing to the read system call.